# Ist falsches Deutsch wie hier wirklich einfacher?

Tags: spelling, sentence-structure, compound

Die CDU hat zur Wahl ein Wahlprogramm in einfacher Sprache erstellt, in welchem sich wie ein roter Faden zwei Fehler beharrlich durchziehen:

- Alle Substantivkombinationen werden qua Bindestrich auseinander gepflückt.
- Sätze beginnen mit Und und Damit, sind dabei unvollständig und ermangeln des Verbs.

Beispiele:

```
An den Hoch-Schulen muss es viele neue Studien-Plätze geben.
Damit mehr junge Leute zur Hoch-Schule gehen.
Damit es in Deutschland mehr Fach-Kräfte gibt.

Wir wollen:
Mehr Über-Wachung.
Mit Kameras.

Verbrecher sollen mehr Angst haben.
Davor, dass sie gefasst werden.
Und davor, dass sie bestraft werden.
```

Wer in der Schule mit Mühe Subjekt-Prädikat-Objekt gelernt hat, wird der nicht durch solche Machwerke verunsichert und erst zum funktionalen Analphabetismus erzogen? Gibt es seriöse Forschungen, die belegen, dass drei kurze Sätze, die die dt. Grammatik verletzen, einfacher zu verstehen sind als ein langer? Bei den Wörtern scheint das gleiche Prinzip angewendet worden zu sein: Statt eines langen Wortes zwei kurze, mit Bindestrich zerstückelte.

`Mehr Über-Wachung.` würde ich auf dem `Über` betonen statt auf dem `wach`, wenn man's richtig schreibt.

Quelle (PDF): http://www.cdu.de/sites/default/files/media/dokumente/regierungsprogramm-in-leichter-sprache-btw13.pdf

Da sich der Text an Wähler richtet, also Personen, die zum Großteil die Schule hinter sich haben und auch im Alltag mit richtigem Deutsch in langen Sätzen konfrontiert werden, sei es in Film und Fernsehen, in Radio oder in Kontakt mit anderen Personen, sollten sie doch, wenn sie auch nur wenig lesen, im Normalfall richtiges Deutsch lesen und gewohnt sein – abgesehen vom Werbesprech, wie wir ihn schon mit `Fein Zucker` diskutiert haben.

Comment: Ich kann mir schon vorstellen, daß es für Quasi-Analphabeten, die sich jedes Wort einzeln aus seinen Buchstaben zusammenreimen, mit Bindestrichen leichter ist. Ob abstrakte Begriffe wie _Studienplatz_ hilfreich sind, halte ich für zweifelhaft; ob man Analphabeten mit dem Versprechen auf mehr Studienplätze überzeugt, auch.

Comment: Was soll denn falsches Deutsch sein?

Comment: Au weia CDU!! Wie peinlich. Ist das denn? Die wähl' ich nicht. Weil dieser Marketing-Sermon. Nicht, auzuhalten ist.

Comment: Über-Wachung... ach du scheiße, das hab' ich ja jetzt erst gesehen. Sorry, aber das ist so doof, das muss Satire sein.

Comment: In dem Programm steht irgendwo auch "Betriebe auf-machen"... ohne Worte, wirk-lich

Comment: Eine weitere Perle: ... "selbst-ständig"

Comment: Für mich wirkt es, als strebe man eine Namensänderung in "Christlich Analphabtische Union" oder in "#CDU_Alter_YOLO" an.

Comment: [FDP](http://www.fdp.de/files/1463/130813_Kurzwahlprogramm_Online_Deutsch_leichte_Sprache_RZ.pdf) (kurz), [Grünen](http://www.gruene.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Dokumente/Wahlprogramm/Bundestagswahlprogramm2013_LeichteSprache.pdf), [Linke](http://www.die-linke.de/fileadmin/download/wahlen2013/kurzfassung_leichte_sprache/bundestagswahlprogramm2013_kurzfassung_leichte_sprache.pdf) (kurz), [Piraten](http://www.piratenpartei.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Wahlprogramm-BTW13-Leichte-Sprache.pdf), [SPD](http://www.spd.de/linkableblob/103836/data/20130628_regierungsprogramm_2013_2017_leichte_sprache.pdf)

Comment: @Emanuel: Nein, das ist im Grunde nicht doof. Das gibt es auch nicht nur bei der CDU, sondern in vielen (öffentlichen) Bereichen. Es hat den ernsthaften Hintergrund, Inhalte auch solchen Leuten nahezubringen, die selbst vor "normalen" Texten schlicht kapitulieren **müssen**. So wie du dich darüber ausläßt, könntest du auch über akustische Blindenampeln herziehen - "man sieht doch, daß Grün ist!"

Comment: Wenigstens wurde "Deutschland" nicht zerlegt. Vielleicht wusste der Ver-Fasser nicht, ob "Deutsch-Land" oder "Deut-Schland" korrekt ist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die [*Verordnung zur Schaffung barrierefreier Informationstechnik nach dem Behindertengleichstellungsgesetz* (kurz **BITV 2.0**)](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bitv_2_0/BJNR184300011.html) enthält in [Anlage 2, Teil 2](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bitv_2_0/anlage_2_9.html) Vorgaben für Bereitstellung von Informationen (im Internet/Intranet) in Leichter Sprache. Unter anderem:

> - "Abkürzungen, Silbentrennung am Zeilenende, Verneinungen sowie Konjunktiv-, Passiv- und Genitiv-Konstruktionen sind zu vermeiden."
> - "Es sind kurze, gebräuchliche Begriffe und Redewendungen zu verwenden. Abstrakte Begriffe und Fremdwörter sind zu vermeiden oder mit Hilfe konkreter Beispiele zu erläutern. Zusammengesetzte Substantive sind durch Bindestrich zu trennen."
> - "Sonderzeichen und Einschübe in Klammern sind zu vermeiden."

Bundesverwaltungsbehörden müssen ihre Websites nach den Vorgaben der BITV 2.0 gestalten, demnach auch die Inhalte in Leichter Sprache anbieten, auf Grundlage dieser genannten Vorgaben. Die ja leider sehr allgemein gehalten sind. Hier beispielsweise die Umsetzungen [des Bundestages](http://www.bundestag.de/leichte_sprache/) und [der Bundesregierung](http://www.bundesregierung.de/Webs/Breg/DE/LeichteSprache/leichteSprache_node.html).

Das Institut für Übersetzungswissenschaft & Fachkommunikation der Universität Hildesheim [schreibt](http://www.uni-hildesheim.de/fb3/institute/institut-fuer-uebersetzungswiss-fachkommunikation/forschung/leichtesprache/was-ist-leichte-sprache/):

> […] Wenn die gesetzlichen Forderungen konsequent umgesetzt werden […], kommt eine große Aufgabe auf uns zu. Diese sollte auf einem wissenschaftlichen Fundament ruhen. Die bisherigen Regeln für Leichte Sprache sind aus der Praxis im Umgang mit Behinderten, vor allem Lernbehinderten, entstanden. Sie sind u.a. in den Anlagen zur BITV 2.0 festgeschrieben.
>
> Dies ist eine gute Basis, aber darüber hinaus ist nun eine Professionalisierung auf wissenschaftlicher Grundlage geboten.
> […]
> Bislang gibt es in Deutschland allerdings keine Forschung, die sich speziell mit diesem Thema beschäftigt.

Publiziert haben die dazu aber [noch](http://www.uni-hildesheim.de/fb3/institute/institut-fuer-uebersetzungswiss-fachkommunikation/forschung/leichtesprache/publikationen/) [nichts](http://www.uni-hildesheim.de/fb3/institute/institut-fuer-uebersetzungswiss-fachkommunikation/forschung/leichtesprache/projekte/masterarbeiten/).

Comment: Ist "Leichter Sprache" ein Markenname, oder wieso wird das groß geschrieben?

Comment: Die Gegner der Neuen Rechtschreibung hatten damals davor gewarnt, daß damit ein Präzedenzfall geschaffen würde, allerdings wurde dieses Argument oft nicht verstanden oder gar mit "Wer, wenn nicht der Staat, soll ...." gekontert. Jetzt fühlt sich der Gesetzgeber offenbar bereits wie selbstverständlich berufen, die Sprache zu regulieren in einer Art und Weise, die Newspeak wie Kinderkram erscheinen läßt.

Comment: Ist es nicht lustig, daß das Bundesministerium mit der Veröffentlichung der Verordnung im Internet diese gleich gebrochen hat?

Answer (score 14):

Wichtig ist hierbei, dass "Leichte Sprache" in erster Linie ein Mittel ist, um Menschen mit Lernschwierigkeiten das Verständnis gerade längerer oder komplexer Texte zu erleichtern. Dass hierbei politische Aussagen klarer werden ist eher ein angenehmer Nebeneffekt.

Die Trennung von zusammengesetzten Wörtern ergibt dabei eigentlich nur Sinn, wenn die Bestandteile eine eigenständige Aussage haben. (Studien-Platz = ein Platz zum Studieren. Hoch-Schule = eine hohe Schule?). Nach meiner Auffassung ist die rigorose Trennung aller zusammengesetzten Wörter in dem Beispiel also falsch.

Die Trennung von Sätzen gerade bei "oder" und "und" in eigenständige Sätze scheint hingegen ein probates Mittel zu sein, die Teilsätze besser auffassen zu können, oft werden auch Aufzählungen verwendet.

Weiteres zu leichter Sprache: [Mensch zuerst](http://www.people1.de/was_halt.html)

---

**Edit:**
Zur Klärung der hier aufgeworfenen Fragen habe ich Kontakt zum Netzwerk Leichte Sprache aufgenommen und die Erlaubnis erhalten, die Antworten hier zu zitieren.
Dabei handelt es sich um die Meinung einer Mitarbeiterin des Vereins, nicht um abgesprochene offizielle Statements.

(Fragen und Antworten hier aus Fließtexten zusammengeschnitten)

Führt die Bindestrich-Trennung von langen/zusammengesetzten Wörtern zu einem erhöhten Leseverständnis?

> Ich würde manche der von Ihnen genannten Wörter nicht trennen. Das hat 
>   sich aber auch im Lauf meiner Arbeit so ergeben:
>   Hochhaus würde ich nicht trennen, das Wort ist nur 8 Zeichen lang.
>   Überwachung würde nicht nicht trennen, weil die beiden Wortteile nicht 
>   gleichwertig (Substantive) sind. Früher habe ich so etwas durchaus auch 
>   getrennt.
>
> Soweit ich es erlebe, benutzen die Menschen mit Lernschwierigkeiten die 
>   Trennungen nur, um das Wort richtig zu lesen. Sie kennen das Wort ja 
>   meistens. Überwachung würde ich in einem oder 2 Sätzen erläutern.
>   Aber sonst habe ich wiederholt erlebt, dass zu lange Wörter falsch 
>   gelesen werden.
>
> Eine Frage dabei ist auch, welche Wörter sind so bekannt, dass eine 
>   Trennung stört. Das erlebe ich durchaus auch.
>
> Ich komme gerade von einer Textprüfung. Ich war mir unsicher gewesen 
>   wegen des Worts Lebensmittel. (mit oder ohne Trennstrich) Meine Prüferin 
>   hat das Wort ohne Trennstrich 2-mal problemlos gelesen. Als es mit 
>   Trennstrich dastand, ist sie beim Lesen gestolpert. Ich gehe davon aus, 
>   dass sehr bekannte Wörter nicht getrennt werden sollten, auch wenn sie 
>   ein bisschen länger sind. Aber das ist meine private Meinung, nicht die 
>   Meinung des Netzwerks.

Ist die Trennung eines Satzes in zwei (grammatikalisch falsche) Sätze erforderlich?
Als Beispiel nannte ich die in den [Regeln für Leichte Sprache](http://www.leichtesprache.org/downloads/Regeln%20fuer%20Leichte%20Sprache.pdf) genannten Satz:

*Im Winter fällt Schnee.

Und es ist kalt.*

> Ich selber würde das Winterbeispiel wahrscheinlich nicht in 2 Sätzen 
>   schreiben. Bei einem längeren Satzzusammenhang mache ich das aber schon.

Bezüglich des "Lernens falscher Grammatik/Schreibweise":

> Die Texte, die wir übersetzen oder 
>   schreiben, sind für Erwachsene gedacht. Sie sind meistens für Kinder 
>   recht uninteressant (Politische Texte, Texte zu Gesundheit, Verträge 
>   etc.) Deshalb gehe ich davon aus, dass diese Texte nur in Ausnahmefällen 
>   von Kindern gelesen werden. Zum Beispiel, wenn es Reiseführer für eine 
>   Stadt sind.

Wie wurden diese Regeln eigentlich entwickelt? Gibts da einen wissenschaftlichen Hintergrund?

> Wenn ich sage, darüber sprechen, bedeutet das immer, dass Menschen mit 
>   Lernschwierigkeiten und Übersetzer gemeinsam darüber sprechen. Nur die 
>   Prüfer können uns sagen, wie es am besten ist.
>
> Und die Leichte Sprache ist in der Praxis entwickelt worden. Menschen 
>   mit Lernschwierigkeiten und Unterstützer haben in einem langen Prozess 
>   überlegt und besprochen, wie Sprache sein sollte, damit sie gut 
>   verständlich ist.
>
> Im Augenblick erforschen aber verschiedene Unis die Leichte Sprache. Es 
>   darf nur nicht dazu führen, dass die Fachleute den Menschen mit 
>   Lernschwierigkeiten vorschreiben, wie sie etwas verstehen müssen.

Das Netzwerk hat das Feedback aber dankend aufgenommen:

> Wir haben beschlossen, dass diese Fragen so wichtig sind, dass wir sie 
>   auf unserer Netzwerkversammlung besprechen möchten.
>
> Ich habe Ihre 1. E-Mail an ein anderes Vorstandsmitglied weitergeleitet. 
>   Wir sind uns einig, dass wir im Netzwerk eine Diskussion über die von 
>   Ihnen und von anderen Menschen aufgeworfenen Fragen führen werden. Mal 
>   sehen, zu welchem Ergebnis wir kommen.

("Prüfer" sind Menschen mit Lernschwierigkeiten, die Texte lesen und nach Verständnis bewerten)

Comment: Die Bindestriche sollen wohl vor allem beim Parsen helfen, dazu müssen es keine zusammengesetzten Substantive sein. Trotzdem find ich „Über-Wachung“ auch zweifelhaft.

Comment: Die Frage ist, ob es Belege dafür gibt, dass 2 kurze Sätze, bei denen der zweite in Wahrheit keiner ist, sondern ein falsch geschriebener Nebensatz, wirklich leichter lesbar ist. Würde es nicht genügen nach einem Komma einen Zeilenumbruch zu machen, so dass die Rechtschreibregeln nicht verletzt werden?

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe meine Antowrt um ein paar Punkte erweitert, die deine Fragen vielleicht beantworten

Comment: Das ist insofern interessant, als nicht nur die Vorstellungen und Ideen des Vereins herangezogen werden, sondern auch empirische, wenn auch wohl keine statistischen, unternommen werden. Auch interessant, dass diese die erwarteten Probleme bestätigen, und schön, dass das so offen kommuniziert wird. Es bestätigt letztlich auch Unors Fazit, dass eine wissenschaftliche Untersuchung noch aussteht.

Answer (score 2):

Neue Regeln zu erfinden bzw. absichtlich fehlerhaft zu schreiben erleichtert nicht, sondern stiftet nur Verwirrung. Das Lesebuch der 1. Klasse wirft auch nicht alle Rechtschreib- und Grammatikregeln über den Haufen. Trotzdem ist es in der Lage, mit dem bestehenden Regelwerk für Anfänger leicht verständlich zu schreiben. Daran hätte man sich hier ein Beispiel nehmen können. Viel schwerer ist es, einmal falsch Erlerntes hinterher wieder zu berichtigen.

Comment: Das ist auch meine Meinung bzw. Kritik, nur beantwortet es nicht meine Frage nach Studien, nach Evidenz. Gibt es Untersuchungen, auf die Du Dich stützen kannst?

Comment: Bestes Bsp.: http://www.derwesten.de/panorama/wie-eine-lernmethode-die-rechtschreibung-der-kinder-verhunzen-kann-id6346743.html - Am Gym hat man noch jahrelang mit den Auswirkungen der Schweizer Methode zu kämpfen

Comment: Es ist jetzt nicht grade so, also ob die Erstlesefibel (Erst-Lese-Fibel?) besonders komplexe Sachverhalte transportieren wollte bzw. müsste. Von daher finde ich das Gegenargument nicht sehr tragfähig.

Answer (score 2):

Aus den Regeln für leichte Sprache [Pdf Dokument](http://www.leichtesprache.org/downloads/Regeln%20fuer%20Leichte%20Sprache.pdf)

Benutzen Sie kurze Wörter.
Wenn das nicht geht:
Trennen Sie lange Wörter mit einem Binde-Strich.

Dann kann man die Wörter besser lesen.

Schlecht: Omnibus
Gut: Bus

Beispiel
Schlecht: Bundesgleichstellungsgesetz
Gut: Bundes-Gleichstellungs-Gesetz

Schreiben Sie kurze Sätze.

Machen Sie in jedem Satz nur eine Aussage.

Auch wenn ich kein Anhänger der besagten politischen Partei bin finde ich es löblich, dass sie ihr Programm in leichter Sprache präsentiert, da der Sinn hinter der leichten Sprache ist, dass

Menschen

- mit Lern-Schwierigkeiten
- mit Demenz
- für die Deutsch eine Fremdsprache ist
- die nicht gut lesen können

komplexe Sachverhalte lesen und verstehen können.

Zitat von @user unknown

> Da sich der Text an Wähler richtet, also Personen, die zum Großteil die Schule hinter sich haben und auch im Alltag mit richtigem Deutsch in langen Sätzen konfrontiert werden, sei es in Film und Fernsehen, in Radio oder in Kontakt mit anderen Personen sollten sie doch, wenn sie auch nur wenig lesen, im Normalfall richtiges Deutsch lesen und gewohnt sein - abgesehen vom Werbesprech wie wir ihn schon mit Fein Zucker diskutiert haben.

Es ist richtig, dass vermutlich viele Personen die Schule hinter sich haben werden, die den Text lesen, aber nicht jeder, der die Schule verläßt, ist in der Lage, perfekt lesen und schreiben zu können. Es ist auch richtig, dass diese Personen tag-täglich mit langen Sätzen konfrontiert werden, aber Personen mit Lese-/Schreibschwächen lavieren sich vielfach aufgrund von "nicht verstehen" durch den Alltag und entfernen sich immer weiter vom "richtigen Deutsch". Daher sind Hilfsmittel wie die leichte Sprache gute "Krücken" zur Integration von Analphabeten.

Comment: Nein, Du überspringst in der Argumentation ein paar wesentliche Punkte! Wenn ein nicht langer, sondern allenfalls mittellanger Satz aus Haupt- und Nebensatz mit einem Punkt statt einem Komma getrennt wird und nach dem Punkt wird groß weitergeschrieben - wieso ist der Text dann leichter zu verstehen? Weil man beide Sätze getrennt und isoliert voneinander verstehen kann? Das kann man ja gerade nicht. Der Nebensatz wird ja nicht durch falsche Zeichensetzung plötzlich zum Hauptsatz. Würde man so umformulieren, dass man 2 kurze Hauptsätze hätte, dann würde ich für möglich halten, es sei leichter.

Comment: Meines Erachtens geht der Versuch von der falschen Prämisse aus, deutsch sei schwer zu lesen. Es ist aber nur schwer zu schreiben. Die vielen Regeln erleichtern das Lesen, und das ist vernünftig, weil oft die Leute, die Schreiben gebildeter sind als die Leser, und weil die meisten Texte nur einmal geschrieben, aber oft gelesen werden. Dass den 4 Personengruppen allen durch die gleichen Hilfsmittel geholfen werden kann ist besonders fraglich. Mit Demenz verhält es sich so, dass der erste Satzteil vergessen ist, bevor das Ende erreicht ist, also macht man rasch einen Punkt?

Answer (score 1):

Es ist auf alle Fälle klarer formuliert, man liest direkter raus was gemeint ist. Sonst wird immer nur um das eigentliche Thema drum herum geredet.

Ich habe selten so klare Aussagen von der CDU gesehen, befreit von jeder Doppeldeutigkeit. Von daher, ja, ich denke durch die fehlende übliche Politiksprache ist es leichter verständlich.

Comment: Die eigentliche Frage bezieht sich aber nicht auf die klar formulierten Aussagen, sondern auf die Abweichungen von grammatikalischem und orthografischem Regelwerk.

Comment: Man kann problemlos die Aussagen in ganze Sätze packen. Es geht mir nicht um den Inhalt sondern um die Schreibung und um den Satzbau. Die Frage ist, ob es in der falschen Schreibung wirklich leichter lesbar ist.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke, diese Frage ist nicht einfach mit einem ja oder nein zu beantworten. Hier fließt viel Subjektivität hinein. Ich habe es als Kind immer so gelernt, dass es ja **die** "Hochschule" ist oder **die** "Überwachung" und somit zusammen geschrieben wird. Ich würde im Nachhinein nie darauf kommen diese Wörter auseinander zu schreiben. Wer es allerdings mit einem Bindestrich zu schreiben gelernt hat, wird dies vermutlich auch als einleuchtend und somit auch für richtig empfinden.

Comment: Hm. Wurde es jemals so unterrichtet, dass es die "Hoch-Schule" oder "die Über-Wachung" sei? Vielleicht bin ich aus der 'falschen Zeit' um das zu verstehen, aber Bindestrich sind imho nur da, um schwierige Wörter lesbar zu machen. Und für Anal-Phabeten, äh sorry, An-Alphabeten mögen Wörter wie "Hochschule" kompliziert sein. Trennt man diese optisch, ist eine Change gegeben, dass diese es verstehen können, da sie die einzelnen Bestandteile erkennen.

Comment: Also ich fühle mich in der Unter-Wachung wohler. ;)

Comment: das war nur Spekulation. Ich hoffe Niemand hat es bisher so gelernt ;)

Comment: Wo fließt Subjektivität hinein? Man schreibt einen Text mal so, mal so, gibt ihn einer ausreichend großen Zahl Probanden und misst, wie lange sie zum Lesen brauchn. Hinterher macht man einen Test, ob der Text von beiden Gruppen gleich gut verstanden wurde. Es ist sicher aufwendig das durchzuführen und ausreichend viele repräsentative Probanden zu finden, die teilnehmen. Da ist überhaupt nichts subjektives dran - entweder man kann es schneller lesen oder nicht.