# "Um zu" versus "als dass"

Tags: word-choice

I saw a post on Facebook with the phrase

> Das Leben ist zu kurz, um Deutsch zu lernen.

Is it also correct to say one of the following:

> - Das Leben ist zu kurz, als dass man Deutsch lernt.
> - Das Leben ist zu kurz, als dass man Deutsch lernen kann.
> - Das Leben ist zu kurz, als dass man Deutsch lernen könnte.

Would any of these be correct or have the same meaning?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, notice that final clauses with *um ... zu* require the subject of the main clause and the implicit subject of the infitivie clause to be the same.<sup>[1](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Final.html?lang=en), [2](https://deutsch.info/en/grammar/syntax#syntax_um_zu), [3](https://www.deutschplus.net/en/pages/Finalsatz), [4](https://learngerman.dw.com/en/final-clauses-um-zu/l-38260879/gr-39391118), [5](http://lerngrammatik.de/en/rules_sentence_final_clause_1.htm)</sup> As an example, consider the sentence:

> Ich brauche Zeit, um Deutsch zu lernen.

Here, both subjects are *ich* (*"ich brauche Zeit"* and *"ich lerne Deutsch"*). Now, consider the sentence:

> <s>Das Leben ist zu kurz, um Deutsch zu lernen.</s>

Here, the subject of the main clause is *das Leben* (*"das Leben ist zu kurz"*), whereas the implicit subject of the infinitive clause is *ich* or *man* (*"ich lerne Deutsch"* or *"man lernt Deutsch"*). In standard German, the sentence is considered wrong; but you may hear or read such uses of *um ... zu* in spite of incongruent subjects in colloquial speech.

---

Some alternatives are the following sentences:

> - Das Leben ist zu kurz, als dass man Deutsch lernen kann. (*indicative*)
> - Das Leben ist zu kurz, als dass man Deutsch lernen könne. (*subjunctive I*)
> - Das Leben ist zu kurz, als dass man Deutsch lernen könnte. (*subjunctive II*)
> - Das Leben ist zu kurz zum Deutschlernen. (*nominalization*)

It is a matter of style, rather than of correctness, which alternative is preferrable. Purists would insist that *als dass* should be used with *subjuctive I* rather than with *indicative*. Still others might argue that, due to the irreal mood, only *subjunctive II* were correct.<sup>[6](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Verb/Kategorien/Modi/Konsekutivsatz.xml?lang=en#id=1.3.2.4.2.4)</sup>

I prefer the latter, succinct alternative; and I dare to assert that—at least in spoken German—it occurs more frequently than the other ones.

---

<sup>**Sources:**

<sup>1</sup> [LEOs deutsche Grammatik](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Final.html?lang=en)

<sup>2</sup> [deutsch.info](https://deutsch.info/en/grammar/syntax#syntax_um_zu)

<sup>3</sup> [deutschplus.net](https://www.deutschplus.net/en/pages/Finalsatz)

<sup>4</sup> [learngerman.dw.com](https://learngerman.dw.com/en/final-clauses-um-zu/l-38260879/gr-39391118)

<sup>5</sup> [lerngrammatik.de](http://lerngrammatik.de/en/rules_sentence_final_clause_1.htm)

<sup>6</sup> [LEOs deutsche Grammatik](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Verb/Kategorien/Modi/Konsekutivsatz.xml?lang=en#id=1.3.2.4.2.4)</sup>

Comment: Your altenatives remind me of the "leichte Sprache" - because for the idiomatic/ quick statement I would avoid a long word like `Deutschlernen`. I'm just surprised about my "observation". See https://german.stackexchange.com/q/7832/36160 for a question about "leichte Sprache".

Comment: Die Regel, die *Das Leben ist zu kurz, um…* schlecht machen soll, gilt in der genannten Form nicht. Vergleiche: *Kritik wird gemieden, um die Gefühle des anderen zu schonen*. *Auch Aqua-Gymnastik ist geeignet, um sich im Alter fit zu halten*.

Comment: Vielleicht paßt das zu der von @jonathan.scholbach angeregten [Meta-Debatte](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen).

Comment: Your prescription is non-sense. Life as a noun is general enough that it may be the indefinite Subject of the infinite clause, even if the semantics appear odd  parsed like that. After all it's someone's life that's talked about, metonymic for that someone.

Comment: Ich finde es wenig hilfreich, Deutschlernenden zu vermitteln, es gäbe eigentlich keine Regeln, und dass wir aus unseren Antworten Aufsätze machen, die „[...] sprachliche Varietäten und auch den Sprachwandel berücksichtigen und auf den eigenen Horizont reflektieren [...]“ (vgl. Herrn  Scholbachs Antwort in der Meta-Debatte), zumal ich auf _colloquial use_ hingewiesen habe.

Comment: Leute, ihr mögt es Nonsense finden, aber diese Regel, oder wie auch immer ihr es nennen wollt, steht nun mal  in zahlreichen Quellen. Wenn die in einer Prüfung abgefragt wird, nützt es dem Deutschlernenden wenig, ob ihr sie gut findet oder nicht. Vor allem könnten man sonst alles in Zweifel ziehen, das in Quellen als Regel aufgeführt wird.

Comment: 1. Canoo bringt selber ein Beispiel mit einem passivischen Matrixsatz, bei dem das Agens, nicht das Subjekt, das verstandene Subjekt der Infinitivkonstruktion angibt: *Der Damm wurde gebaut, um Überschwemmungen zu verhindern.* 2. Es finden sich zahlreiche Beispiele der Art *Dieser Landstrich ist zu schön, um sich nur an einem Platz aufzuhalten*, wo *man* das verstandene Subjekt der Infinitivkonstruktion ist. 3. Die Regel bedarf mindestens der Ergänzung durch die zwei genannten Ausnahmen. Die Gefahr von Punktabzug sehe ich bei einem korrekten deutschen Satz nie.

Comment: @DavidVogt Zu 1.: _Das Leben ist zu kurz_ ist kein Passiv. Zu 2.: In Netz findet man zu fast allem zahlreiche Beispiele. Dieser Umstand führt nicht automatisch zu ihrer standardsprachlichen Richtigkeit (vgl. z.B. die in sozialen Medien häufig anzutreffende Getrenntschreibung zusammengesetzter Wörter). Zu 3.: Ich sträube mich, jetzt aus meinen Antworten Aufsätze mit Untersuchungen zu sämtlichen Ausnahmen und Sprachvariationen machen zu müssen. Der Hinweis _colloquial_ sollte ja wohl genügen. Und da der seit Beginn da steht, finde ich die Diskussion absurd. Man kann's auch übertreiben!

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing itself is "correct enough" in all examples.

About the nuances:

> Das Leben ist zu kurz, um Deutsch zu lernen.

In my opinion that is generally used to describe that the second part (um Deutsch zu lernen) is a task that requires personal work and effort. This is the general meaning that is provided by all given examples. They differ in the matter of "what has to be pointed out".

> Das Leben ist zu kurz, als dass man Deutsch lernt.

Similiar to the first one with a little bit stressing the point that it seems impossible to do it.

> Das Leben ist zu kurz, als dass man Deutsch lernen kann

Combination of first and second: the personal work and effort is to high to achieve this goal - if it is possible in general.

> Das Leben ist zu kurz, als dass man Deutsch lernen könnte

This phrase claims that noone is able to master the german language in its life. It implies that there is no need to consider the personal work and effort, it will be more than fits into a span of life.

With "correct enough" I'd like to point out that I see them in spoken language as correct, I just would not use all of them.

For me the first (commonly known) structure seems universal in German, the second one would be the lazy form of the last one - I would prefer the last over the second but I would speak out loud the second. Only the third example I would not come up on my own.